# set_include_path Not working exactly

Tags: php

I'm doing a MVC system for myself. Everything is okey buth when i tried include db connection file with `set_include_path`, it is not including.

Autoload.php:

```
set_include_path("app/Controllers".PATH_SEPARATOR."app/Models".PATH_SEPARATOR."system/config");
spl_autoload_register();
```

app/Controllers and app/Models part working true. Just system/config not including.

Here is the my file system:

```
app
 Controllers
 Models
 Views

system
  router
  config
    db.php
  autoload.php
```

Comment: any errors or warnings or notices generated or logged? Have you got that switched on?

Comment: no, not giving error just: "Fatal error: Trait 'connect' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\app\Models\Users.php on line 3". when i add with include "system/config/db.php"; manually, it is working. i deleted all db lines and just write die("hellooooooo"); but it is not working. i mean not including..

Comment: And this `connect` trait is something which is part of db.php, I assume? Also is `system` actually part of your PHP application's folder structure? include paths are relative to the root. And check you don't have any other settings e.g. in .htaccess files which might override this.

Comment: yes. but when i delete all db codes and just put die("hellooooooo"); it is still not working. it is not including.

Comment: Also check if `spl_autoload_register();` returns true...it can return `false` on failure, as per the docs. Also, as per your code "autoload.php" won't get included...did you intend that?

Comment: i dont know how to take return per the docs. but im using get_included_files and db file is not here

Comment: well, it's just like any other function.... e.g. `$result = spl_autoload_register(); var_dump($result);`

Comment: my autoload.php is included to router/route.php. file is working. Just not including third part

Comment: You could also check that set_include_path() returns correctly in the same way.

Comment: it is giving true

Comment: "my autoload.php is included to router/route.php"...but "router" is not in your include path... Neither is your Views folder.

Comment: set_include_path giving this: string(17) "C:\xampp\php\PEAR"

Comment: Well the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) say "Returns the old include_path on success or FALSE on failure."...so if that was your old include path, then that suggests it's considered valid, at least. You can always run http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php to check the new one is what you expected.

Comment: can you give a example?

Comment: err... `echo get_include_path();`? Sorry but do you understand how to call a function and output the result? Or you could try reading the links I give you which contain very easy examples... sorry to be impatient but that is like day 1 php, if you're already on to autoloading then you shouldn't need to ask me that.

Comment: of course i know but it is returning "app/Controllers;app/Models;system/config". so? what should i do :)

Comment: One other thing, read http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path as well, there is some stuff about relative paths. And since you're on Windows, are you sure you should be using `/` as your directory separator? There is a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant which will handle it for you. Since some of the folders are already included, it seems like it may be handling it for you anyway but it might be worth doing it the recommended way, since you're having an odd problem.

Comment: i still cant find the problem :D it is so interesting for me

Comment: i found. trait name and file name must be same name. my trait name connect and file name was db. it is giving error because of this. i rename the file "connect" from "db" and it is working now. thank you.

Comment: So nothing to do with the include path?

Comment: yes. the code or paths was true. just renamed the file name connect.php from db.php . because trait my trait name is connect

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I didn't know that. You should add it as the answer for future readers. You're allowed to accept your own answers, and also others can upvote them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Trait name and file name must be same. I rename the file "connect.php" from "db.php". Because my trait name is "connect".